# Isolate Server Name From UNC with FOR in Batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, unc

The goal of my overall script is to - from a central server - check individual site servers for files. If files exist, go do some work. This smaller exerpt is to aid creation of multiple entries for site names, logs, dates, and times of which I want to check the UNC path and use a variable for the site server name - the first 'token' of the UNC path. I used the example guide from [Rob van der Woude's](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php) scripting page (these loops are new to me and it appears to be a basic resource) to create the `FOR` loop exampled below.

```
@echo off
SET PATH=\\UNCMainPath\SubPath1\SubPath2
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=\" %%A IN (%PATH%) DO SET FOLDER=%%A
ECHO %FOLDER%
```

This is short and clean and will be easy to repeat for ~50 site servers. This code, however, does not work. The error I receive is:

> The system cannot find the file \\UNCMainPath\SubPath1\SubPath2.
>
> ECHO is off.

This, of course, tells me something is wrong before the `FOR` loop begins, but for the life of me I can't figure what is incorrect. Even with trash example text, I've been able to `SET` a variable and have it `ECHO` back as whatever it was set for. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Insert face in to palm and sigh  ... quotes did it! I feel really silly. Thank you.

Comment: also, don't use `%path%` for a variable, especially without setlocal. It's a reserved environment variable.

Comment: Thank you @MattWilliamson. I did not know that. I will switch to something more generic.

Comment: You're welcome. Open a `CMD` prompt and type `SET` to see the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Endoro.

Using `("%PATH%")` did the trick. I forgot to enclose the variable with quotes.